# Refactor SQL update with subquery to affect multiple rows

Tags: sql, mariadb

I have a working SQL query that calculates inventory turnover rate and updates a specified product record. I'd like to refactor this query to calculate and update turnover for multiple table rows. My problem is that the working query (below) includes a product_id in a subquery join clause and I can't figure out how to remove it.

```sql
UPDATE products
SET turnover = (
    WITH RECURSIVE
        -- Generate a table of dates from the last year
        daterange AS (
            SELECT CURDATE() AS date, 1 AS n
            UNION ALL
            SELECT date - INTERVAL 1 DAY, n + 1
            FROM daterange
            WHERE n < 365
        ),
        -- Generate a table of historic inventory AS worth
        history AS (
            SELECT daterange.date, IFNULL(SUM(units.price), 0) worth
            FROM daterange
            LEFT JOIN units
                -- Include units that were acquired before the date
                ON DATE(units.acquired_at) < daterange.date
                -- ...and released after the date, or not at all
                AND (DATE(units.released_at) > daterange.date OR units.released_at IS NULL)
                -- ...and units that are not our specified product
                AND units.product_id = 20593
            GROUP BY daterange.date
        ),
        -- Generate a table of inventory sale totals from the last year
        sales AS (
            SELECT product_id, SUM(price) AS year_total
            FROM units
            WHERE released_at > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 YEAR)
            GROUP BY product_id
        )
    -- Calculate turnover as annual sales divided by average inventory
    SELECT (sales.year_total) / AVG(history.worth) turnover
    FROM history
    LEFT JOIN sales ON sales.product_id = products.id
)
WHERE id = 20593;
```

I would like to be able to remove the where clause on the outer query, or replace it with something like `WHERE products.type_id = 5` to work on multiple rows. But this can't be done without removing `units.product_id = 20593` from the history subquery, and substituting `units.product_id = products.id` throws an error "**Unknown column products.id in on clause**."

For clarity, there are two tables being used here: products and units. Minimally, they have the following columns:

| products | units |
| --- | --- |
| id | id |
| type_id | product_id |
| turnover | price |
|  | acquired_at |
|  | released_at |

Any advice appreciated! I'm open to exploring different approaches to this problem. I'm using MariaDB (v15.1).

Comment: `LEFT JOIN sales ON sales.product_id = history.product_id` surely? And then `select` that column in the `history` CTE. Is this even valid, are you allowed to put a CTE inside a subquery like that?

Comment: @Charlieface if I understand correctly, you're suggesting something like this: 
`history AS (SELECT daterange.date, units.product_id, IFNULL(SUM(units.price), 0) AS worth [...] GROUP BY daterange.date, units.product_id)`. The problem with this is that `AVG(history.worth)` then average the value of *all* products. Maybe there's a way to select for only the history rows with a matching product_id (or null)? I'll play with that.

Comment: No it will be the average per each `group by` set, so per date and productId

Comment: You could use a stoted procdure instead of one overly complicated query. That way you could break up the complexity into more manageable pieces. It would also be easier to optimize.

Comment: what does `select version();` show?  v15.1 isn't a thing

Comment: you don't have to join to a dates table, instead you can for each row calculate how many days each unit was in inventory and do `sum(price * inventory_days) / days in year`

Comment: `DATE(units.acquired_at) < daterange.date` shouldn't this be `<=`?  does a unit not count as inventory on the day it is acquired?  as is, it only counts beginning the following day. I guess that is what the comment says

Comment: for sales you are looking at a full year (including the current date) but for inventory only 365 days?  seems like these should be consistent.

Comment: and a final comment: perhaps make your period end yesterday, not today?  as is, if you run this, and later today a unit is released, your update will have been incorrect, so you'd only be able to run this after all updates for the day are complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using conditional aggregation, you can calculate both sales and average inventory in a single query with no joins.

I have kept your existing logic of considering inventory for only days between the acquire date and the release date, *non inclusive*, though that seems strange to me.  But I have adjusted the date range for inventory to match sales.

```
select
  product_id,
  sum(case when date(released_at) > curdate() - interval 1 year and date(released_at) <= curdate() then price end) sales,
  sum(greatest(0, datediff(
    least(curdate() + interval 1 day, coalesce(date(released_at), curdate() + interval 1 day)),
    greatest(curdate() - interval 1 year, date(acquired_at))
  ) - 1) * price) / datediff(curdate(), curdate() - interval 1 year) avg_inventory
from units
group by product_id
```

Updating turnover based on this is simple; here I only update products that have had any inventory in the year, adjust as needed:

```
update products
join (
  select
    product_id,
    sum(case when date(released_at) > curdate() - interval 1 year and date(released_at) <= curdate() then price end) sales,
    sum(greatest(0, datediff(
      least(curdate() + interval 1 day, coalesce(date(released_at), curdate() + interval 1 day)),
      greatest(curdate() - interval 1 year, date(acquired_at))
    ) - 1) * price) / datediff(curdate(), curdate() - interval 1 year) avg_inventory
  from units
  group by product_id
  having avg_inventory
) summary on id = product_id
set turnover = coalesce(sales,0) / avg_inventory
```

For purposes of understanding, here's an intermediate query showing the effects on sales and inventory and inventory calculation for each units row:

```
select id, acquired_at, released_at,
  product_id,
  case when date(released_at) > curdate() - interval 1 year and date(released_at) <= curdate() then price end sales,
  greatest(curdate() - interval 1 year, date(acquired_at)) after_date,
  least(curdate() + interval 1 day, coalesce(date(released_at), curdate() + interval 1 day)) before_date,
  greatest(0, datediff(
    least(curdate() + interval 1 day, coalesce(date(released_at), curdate() + interval 1 day)),
    greatest(curdate() - interval 1 year, date(acquired_at))
  ) - 1) inventory_days,
  price,
  greatest(0, datediff(
    least(curdate() + interval 1 day, coalesce(date(released_at), curdate() + interval 1 day)),
    greatest(curdate() - interval 1 year, date(acquired_at))
  ) - 1) * price / datediff(curdate(), curdate() - interval 1 year) avg_inventory
from units
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/nlw1pnP3)

Comment: This is a fantastic approach. It works as expected and executes much faster than the query patterns I was using. Thanks for taking the extra time to explain and include an intermediate query!

Answer (score 0):

There is a much simpler (and probably faster) way to generate a table of consecutive dates *in MariaDB*:

```
SELECT '2023-01-01' + INTERVAL seq-1 DAY AS a_date
    FROM seq_1_to_365
```

Then toss the `WITH` and have something like

```
UPDATE ( the above query ) AS dates
    LEFT JOIN products AS p  ON p.date = dates.a_date
    SET p...
```

Comment: Wow, that is a fantastic alternative to the recursive statement I was using. Thank you! Unfortunately, I am still having the issue rewriting the subquery to generate historic inventory worth.

Comment: Update your question with the improved query.